# Experience Manager: Different publications for saving and localizing

Tags: 2011, experience-manager

We have a blueprint whereby all components are created at the publication 02 Global Content. A number of language publications which inherit from this are used for translating components.

Is there a way of setting up experience manager to always create components at 02 Global Content but always localize at 03 French for example. Looking at the Blueprint context settings it only allows for one alternative publication for saving and localizing.

Has anyone been able to get around this with custom events code or have any ideas as to how this could be achieved?

Comment: Did you look into (ab)using Content Types for this?

Comment: Asier heard you and added an example, @FrankvanPuffelen. :-) Looks like we have three considerations for handling the save context: multiple XPM sites, multiple Content Types, and/or the event system as an (additional) option for automation. Personally, I like Content Types. We start with them in (IA) analysis, and come back to them in Experience Manager. ;-)

Answer (score 8):

This can be easily achieved by configuring Experience Manager accordingly to your needs.

Just follow these steps to configure everything as needed:

1. Configure General Content to be created in publication 02 Global
   Content. This is done when you create the Content Type (in
   Experience Manager terminology).
2. Configure the French Website Publication to have localized content
   created in 03 French Content. This is done from the Dashboard -
   Settings - Blueprint Context Settings - 03 French Content
   Publication, as shown in the red box in the image below.

Now, any localization done in the French Website will be stored in the 03 French Content. However, any content type that is created from this same website will be stored wherever that content type was configured to be stored.

[image]

Follow these steps from Experience Manager to get the content in the publication you want it:

3. To create content in 02 Global Content, just create any content from
   Experience Manager and this will be automatically stored in 02
   Global Content.
4. To create content in 03 French Content, from Experience Manager
   create content and then localize it, this will be automatically
   localized into 03 French Content. All the configuration can be done
   from the Experience Manager Dashboard settings, you need to uncheck
   the check-box that says "Also create components in this Publication"

With this set up, you can accomplish just what you want. I have tested this myself to make sure I don't mislead you.

Answer (score 7):

I do not think you can do that but:
If you do have for instance a 05 French Web publication, you can set the "Blueprint context for Components" for this particular publication to 03 French so that XPM always creates and localizes content in 03 French. 
The common practice is to create English content from the English preview website (through XPM), and French content from the French preview website.

Comment: If all content must be created at the master publication and the master publication is english than no content may be created in the french publication (it would need to be created in the english publication first and then localized).

This behaviour can be enforced through the event system if necessary by hooking the component save pre event; if the component is being created in the french publication create it in the english master instead; localize and finally save the localized component in the french publication.

Comment: Good point, @BjørnvanDommelen, this could enforce publication locations (save context) regardless of content type settings. It might not fit a small BluePrint, but can definitely save time managing many content types for larger organizations.